# Cordova ionic create Android App Keystore

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I made the application using Ionic Cordova

Now I want to assemble it and suggested that I create a key at the assembly stage.
On the official site it offers to execute the command in the console

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore MY-RELEASE-
KEY.keystore -alias MY_ALIAS_NAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

but where exactly should it be performed?
In what directory is the nada?
Do I need to install android SDK or android Studio.

Who had the experience of building applications, tell me how to do everything correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Keytool and jarsigner comes with the java jdk. You can run it wherever you want.
2. The zipalign tool can be found in `/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign`. For example, on OS X with Android Studio installed, zipalign is in `~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign`

Just follow everything here. Of course you need JDK
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html